# Automatically have += defined when defining +?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a type that has a custom `+` defined for it. I was wondering if it was possible for Swift to automatically write a definition for `+=`, namely `a += b` --> `a = a+b`. Ideally I would not have to write the corresponding assignment operator for each operator I write.

Sample code:

```
class A {
    var value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    static func +(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> A {
        return A(lhs.value + rhs.value)
    }
}

var a = A(42)
let b = A(10)

// OK
let c = a + b

// error: binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two 'A' operands
// Ideally, this would work out of the box by turning it into a = a+b
a += b
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the overloaded operator method?

Comment: @ZeMoon I added sample code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you have to define `+=` when you define `+`.

You could create a `Summable` protocol that declares both `+` and `+=`, but you'll still have to define the `+` function since addition of arbitrary types has no concrete meaning.  Here's an example:

```
protocol Summable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    static func +=(lhs: inout Self, rhs: Self)
}

extension Summable {
    static func +=(lhs: inout Self, rhs: Self) { lhs = lhs + rhs }
}

struct S: Summable { }

func +(lhs: S, rhs: S) -> S {
    // return whatever it means to add a type of S to S
    return S()
}

func f() {
    let s0 = S()
    let s1 = S()
    let _ = s0 + s1

    var s3 = S()

    s3 += S()  // you get this "for free" because S is Summable
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason Swift doesn't do this automatically?

Comment: For simple types such as `Int` `+=` is well-defined.  When you have a more complex custom type then there may be side-effects to modifying the left hand side of the `+=` equation that you don't want.  For simplicity and/or safety constructing a new object every time by using `+` may be the only correct thing to do.  So explicit declaration of `+=` is the correct requirement from Swift's point of view.  When you use `Summable` you are saying you understand (and are ok with) the side-effects of `+=`.

Comment: I figured that writing `+=` would imply you were ok with performing addition. I assumed it was syntactic sugar, not a real component of the language.

Comment: Remember that `+=` changes one of its arguments.  There are many complex types for which mutation is either disallowed entirely, or mutation must follow a very well-defined path. In these types of objects a `+` operator may make sense, but `+=` would be forbidden.  Since Swift can't know *a priori* what the requirements of an arbitrary custom type might be, it can't assume that auto-generating `+=` when a custom `+` is available is a valid thing to do.  So no, it's not syntactic sugar.  `+=` is a full-fledged operator in its own right.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Forgot that `+=` could change `lhs` arbitrarily. Still, I wish there was some way to opt in to the "vanilla" behavior where `a += b` == `a = a+b`.